# restore or keep events of select after .replaceWith()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, event-listener, replacewith

I'm rebuilding a **select** via javascript to adjust contained **option** elements based on user input.

On initial page load I'm storing all **select options** in "countryOptions" and based on user input I match all contained **select options** of my "countryOptions" with the new subset and create a new **select** element as "newSelect" to write it into the DOM with `.replaceWith(newSelect)`.

The **select** Element has an on change listener:

```
$(countrySelector).on('change', function(){...});
```

I don't use `.html()` because there are known issues in some IE versions when using `.html()` on a **select** element. Upon replacing the **select** element with `.replaceWith()` all event handlers are removed as intended by `.replaceWith()`.

I don't use CSS to "hide" **select option** elements, because that doesn't work cross browser.

Now I'm looking for an alternative that works cross browser or a way to keep/restore my event handlers. Any ideas?

Comment: What about delegated event handlers?

Comment: If you use `clone()` inside `replaceWith()` and pass true to it : `$('element').clone(true)` the event handlers are copied.

Comment: What is `countrySelector`, a selector string?

Comment: @A.Wolff `countrySelector` contains the ID of the used **select** element, in this case "#country"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest would be to use delegate event handlers which you can bind everytime you replace your elements. But if you don't want to or can't do that for whatever reason, you can get all event handlers with

```
$._data( countrySelector, "events" );
```

But be aware that countrySelector needs to be the html and not the jQuery element. It returns an Object with all handlers which you then can bind to the new element.

Code Example for delegates:

```
function countrySelectorChange() {
   // do your magic
}
```

Then bind the delegate to the event:

```
$(countrySelector).on('change', countrySelectorChange);
```

Repeat this for every added item you need it for.

```
newSelect.on('change', countrySelectorChange);
```

Comment: You were head on with your idea to use a delegated event handler. I accepted the other reply because I saw it first and it has a code example. Your answer is good nevertheless because you named  the correct answer and even provided an alternative... hard to choose between both answers. If you would include a short code sample, I'd give the green arrow to you as it will be most helpfull for other users.

Comment: I did add the example. Not for the arrow but for elaborating what I meant. The other solution is fine as it is. I personally prefer not to use "global" event handlers whenever I can, but it is a valid and simple solution nontheless.

Answer (score 3):

may help

```
$(document).on('change', countrySelector , function(){...});
```

Comment: Sometimes the solution is so simple that no facepalm would suffice... This fixed it for me and I even understand it... should have seen it myself. Thank you!